# The best overload for '.ctor' does not have a parameter named 'throwIfV1Schema'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm using asp.net identity in my web application. When i run it gives the following error:

> The best overload for '.ctor' does not have a parameter named 'throwIfV1Schema'

The code is Here:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
 {
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

}

the error is in the line: `base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)`

Kindly suggest solution
Thanks in advance

Comment: There are various `IdentityDbContext<TUser>` types. One is in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613070(v=vs.108).aspx, which definitely has that constructor. Which version do you use and why do you want to provide this parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried removing `throwIfV1Schema:` like the following, it should solve the problem:

```
public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection",  false)
```

Depending on the .NET version, maybe you can even try it without the boolean. It is generally used like it, indeed:

```
public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
```

Comment: This is no solution, it's a guess.